# Is this the right way to do lambda method chaining in python?

Tags: python, lambda

I come from java background and I am trying to implement lambda chaining in **Python**. Below is my code

```
li = ["amol", "vikas", "rahul"]
li2 = list(filter(lambda n: (n == "Amol"), list(map(lambda name: (name.capitalize()), li))))
print(li2)
```

This Function will

- Capitalize the names
- Filter the names with "Amol"

Currently the code is **running well** but it seems to be cluttered and complicated when compared to java

Comment: "_when compared to java_", can you show the java equivalent?

Comment: `myList.stream().map(name -> name.functionToCapitalize()).filter(name -> name.equals("Amol")).collect(toList())`

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This looks "dumbed down" code: If you can, please show running code from a project where this came up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off doing an inline list comprehension.

```
li2 = [name.capitalize() for name in li if name == "amol"]
```

For the lambda implementation itself, you can leave the map and filter generators until only when you want to convert back to list:

```
li2 = filter(lambda n: n == "Amol", map(str.capitalize, li))
print(list(li2))
```

Comment: sorry for my english but i did not get the meaning of "you can leave the map and filter generators until only when you want to convert back to list"

Comment: got it. li2 should be just a stream object as we have in java

Comment: @amol updated the `map` function call.